# Background Image Appearing Over Text

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a simple menu that I built and that I'm trying add animations to. I added a slide on hover animation but when you hover over the item the slide animation goes over the text blocking it. I'm pretty sure its going to be an easy fix that I'm over looking but help would be appreciated. The issue is coming from these CSS classes I'm pretty sure:

```
.nav2Active{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width:100px;
    border-left:thin solid transparent;
    background:transparent;
}

.nav2Active::before{
    content:'';
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    height:30px;
    width:0%;
    -webkit-transition:width .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:width .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:width .3s ease-out;
    z-index:0;
}

.nav2Active a{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.nav2Active:hover::before{
    border-left:thin solid #F60;
    width:100px;
}

.nav2Active:active{
    background: #CCC;
    border-left: #F60;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pwfv33hs/

Comment: put a `z-index:-10;` instead of `z-index:0;` on your `.nav2Active::before`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay its very easy do this :

```
.nav2Active:hover::before{
    border-left:thin solid #F60;
    width:100px;
    z-index:-1
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was going to be something simple haha. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

It's a `z-index` issue, you set a value for the pseudo element `= 0`.

```
.nav2Active::before{
    z-index:0;
}
```

But all elements has the same value as default. In order to work you can set a `-1` value. But I don't like to work with that negative values. I suggest this:

```
.nav2Active a{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Check the **[UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwfv33hs/1/)**